# How to test if one, two or both variables are blank or nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 columns (**column_a** and **column_b**)in database - both are strings. I need to test, if **column_a** or **column_b** or both are **nil** or **blank**.

What's the best way to do that?
What I am currently doing is that I am testing **column_a** and then **column_b** - the thing is that I need to run the same code for both of these variables.

What's the most efficient way to test the above?

Comment: Efficient in what way? If you need to test them both, you need to test them both.

Answer (score 1):

You can with arbitrary number of variables

`[column_a, column_b].collect(&:to_s).all? :empty?`

or if at least one has to be nil or blank

`[column_a, column_b].collect(&:to_s).any? :empty?`

Answer (score 1):

The best way I think is to define a custom method in your model

```
def a_and_b
    (columna.blank? || columna.nil?).to_i + (columnb.blank? || columnb.nil?).to_i*2
end
```

Possible values:
 0: none empty or blank
 1: a empty or blank
 2: b empty or blank
 3: both empty or blank

Call like this:

```
record.a_and_b
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to map an array of those values.  E.g.

`[ column_a, column_b ].map { |x| x.nil? || x.empty? }`

You'll end up with an array of booleans telling you which are nil/empty.  You could then ask that resulting question whether any are empty (`result.any?` / `result.all?`).

Answer (score 0):

```
[column_a, column_b].all?{|e| e.to_s.strip.empty?}
```

Or in Rails:

```
column_a.blank? && column_b.blank?
```